# How to fetch the live app version programmatically?

Tags: java, android, version, in-app-update

Initially, to fetch the live app version programmatically I was using the following snippet

```
 try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
                    .get(7)
                    .ownText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But at the end of May 2022, this snippet started throwing exceptions. Is anyone having a similar issue?
Any fixes are very welcome.

*****Solution*****

Google Provides an official solution for this now

> Use *AppUpdateManager*

from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#java)

Check for update availability

> Before requesting an update, you need to first check if one is
> available for your app. To check for an update, use AppUpdateManager,
> as shown below:
>
> ```
> // Creates instance of the manager. 
>  AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context);
>     
> // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
> Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();
>     
> // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update. appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
>         if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
>               // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
>               && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
>                   // Request the update.
>         } });
> ```
>
> The result contains the update availability status. If an update is
> available and the update is allowed, the returned AppUpdateInfo also
> contains an intent to start the update. See the next section for how
> to start the update.
>
> If an in-app update is already in progress, the result will also
> report the status of the in-progress update.

This worked for me. Hope it helps !

Comment: what is the exception stacktrace

Comment: Hi Junaid, It's IndexOutOfBounds Exception on ".select(".hAyfc .htlgb")"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, google updated their play store website, that solution no longer works. The dom structure has changed, app versions are no hidden behind a modal that is dynamically loaded.  I  am currently in the process of trying to find a new solution as well.